# Why did it generate many pom files when I every time execute uploadArchives?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I wrote my gradle script for publishing my module as an artifact. I'm using the internal maven repository of our company. I execute

> gradle uploadArchives

It was a success. Then I browsed the webpage of the publish url, the pom.xml is in there.

> lib.core.imageprocessor-1.0.0.develop-20161025.140959-1.pom

Every thing was ok. But when I executed this task a second time, I found that it has generated another pom file. look:

> lib.core.imageprocessor-1.0.0.develop-20161026.051357-2.pom

It will generate new pom files with x.pom (x increase by number) when I executed the upload task every time. So there will be a lot of pom.xml files in the repository.

Why did it generate a different name pom file? Did I do something wrong？

Here is the code:

```
 uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            configurePOM(pom)
            repository(url: "http://10.10.106.128:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/") {
                authentication(userName: 'xxx', password: 'xxx')
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: "http://10.10.106.128:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots") {
                authentication(userName: 'xxx', password: 'xxx')
            }
        }
    }
}

private configurePOM(def pom) {
    pom.project {
        groupId 'com.gaogao.android'
        artifactId imageprocessor
        String ver = "1.0.0." + “develop” + "-SNAPSHOT"
        version ver
        name 'com.gaogao.android'
        packaging 'aar'
        description "Lib For Android"
        url "http://10.10.106.128:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/"
        inceptionYear "2016"
        developers {
            developer {
                id "android_team"
                name "android_team"
                email "android_team@xxx.com"
                url "http://www.gaogao.com"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNAPSHOTs are intermediate versions until you are releasing one of them. A `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` will result in an `1.0.0` release version. Because you can have multiple attempts to get your SNAPSHOT ready for release. Only `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` is not sufficient to identify an artifact so it gets suffixed.

For Maven (and maybe gradle, not sure) there are options to "always update SNAPSHOT dependencies", what does pick the latest (or greatest) `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` determined by the suffix.

If you are using Sonatype Nexus or a similar tool, this is the one responsible for the suffixes and maybe has some policies for its snapshot-repo, where this can be modified. You can (and should) also adjust the removal of unused SNPASHOT-artifacts here (timebased or otherwise).

In a release-repo the suffixing is forbidden, or at least not a good idea, because here the versions are unique.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  your answer is perfect.  I'll accept it.